# The order of $PATH in .bashrc

Tags: bash, python, anaconda

I installed anaconda which appends before $PATH in my .bashrc file like:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

whenever I run python from terminal, it calls anaconda version python, not system python. I wonder it could cause a problem in the future because when I make update on the system, it will continue anaconda python. It worries me because it could unstable the system in the future.

My preference is not the order above but:

```
  $ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/anaconda/bin
```

I wonder it could make a problem for anaconda installation.

Comment: Naah. As long as you either use the 2.* -or- the 3.* version of python for both it will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't cause any issues, because as long as it is in the `$PATH` environment variable, `bash` should know where it is and be able to invoke it from any directory.

That being said, I have not used `anaconda` before so I can't speak to whether or not that specific program would have any issues, but it shouldn't.